# Solving equations using rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Suppose I'm solving the following equation and try to find unique values for $v$ that satisfies $Av=u$.

If $A$ is a square matrix and invertible, then $v$ is easily determined as $v=A^{-1}u$.

However if $A$ is not a square matrix, do you know what condition guarantees uniqueness of $v$? For instance, $A$ is $m\times n$, $v$ is $n \times 1$, and $u$ is $m \times 1$, where $m\neq n$. In this case, I'm wondering the condition of a matrix $A$ to guarantee the uniqueness of $v$, if it exists.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

The equation $Av=u$ has, at most, one solution if and only if the null space of $A$ is $\{0\}$.